# Reverse Johnson transformation

Tags: r, transformation

I want to perform a regression and I have a data set with a left-skewed target variable (Murder) like this:

```
data("USAArrests")

str(USAArrests)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Murder  : num  13.2 10 8.1 8.8 9 7.9 3.3 5.9 15.4 17.4 ...
 $ Assault : int  236 263 294 190 276 204 110 238 335 211 ...
 $ UrbanPop: int  58 48 80 50 91 78 77 72 80 60 ...
 $ Rape    : num  21.2 44.5 31 19.5 40.6 38.7 11.1 15.8 31.9 25.8 ...


hist(USAArrests&Murder)
```

[image]

Since the data is left-skewed. I can do a log transformation of the target in order to improve the performance of the model.

```
train = USArrests[1:30,]

train$Murder = log(train$Murder)

test = USArrests[31:50,]
```

If I want to apply this model on the test set a have to reverse the transformation to get the actual result. This I can do by `exp`.

```
fit = lm(Murder~., data = train)

pred = predict(fit, test)

exp(pred)
```

However, in my case, the log transformation is not enough to get a normal distribution of the target. So I used the Johnson transformation.

```
library(bestNormalize)

train$Murder = yeojohnson(train$Murder)$x.t
```

Is there a possibility to reverse this transformation like the log transformation like above?

Comment: From the help page, section Details: *This transformation can be performed on new data, and **inverted**, via the `predict` function*. My emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Rui Barradas, the `predict` function can be used here. Instead of directly pulling out `x.t` from the `yeojohnson` function, you can do the following:

```
# Store the transformation object
yj_obj <- yeojohnson(train$Murder)

# Perform transformation
yj_vals <- predict(yj_obj)

# Reverse transformation
orig_vals <- predict(yj_obj, newdata = yj_vals, inverse = TRUE)

# Should be the same as the original values
all.equal(orig_vals, train$Murder)
```

The same workflow can be done with the log and exponentiation transformation via the `log_x` function (together with the `predict` function and the `inverse = TRUE` argument).